# Populate combobox inside DataGridView with the values of List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to add a Combobox inside a DataGridView the method where I am managing this is repeated plenty of times if I refresh another combobox that I have in Windows form, I run this method all over again

```
this.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = Constants.Vacation_Calendar.Total_Calendar_Days + 2;
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Resource";
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Month";
this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 60;



DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
List<Process> getAllProcesses = this.bl_process.getAll_Process();
List<String> getApplication= new List<string>();


foreach (Process process in getAllProcesses)
{
    getApplication.Add(process.Application);
}



if (!DataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Any(x => x.Name == "ProcessColumn"))
{
    cb.HeaderText = "Process";
    cb.Name = "ProcessColumn";
    cb.Width = 100;
    cb.DataSource = getApplication;
    cb.ReadOnly = false;
    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, cb);
}
```

I keep getting an Error that I handled with the following code in the designer:

```
this.DataGridView1.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.DataGridView1_DataError);
```

And in code behind:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e){}
```

with all this I can't see my list populating the combobox, what's still missing here?

Thank you so much in advance

PS: I added "getApplication" object to the Quickwatches and it's receiving all the values from my List, so it's all good.

Comment: Are you sure that lines inside `if` statement are executed ? Did you breakpoint it ?

Comment: in Watches output i added "DataGridView1.Columns[2]" and "cb" i added a breakpoint inside that if statement and my cb object has a dataSource with a count of 3271 and that is fine , the problem is when i check   DataGridView1.Columns[2]" it seems that there's nothing inside when i reach the end of the if statement

Comment: Can you try `AddRange` instead of `DataSource`, like this `cb.Items.AddRange(getApplication.ToArray());`

Comment: didn't work. One thing im not sure if it's because of the error im getting if i remove that method to handle the error. If i remove it i get an error of System.ArgumentException:DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid. To replace this default dialog please handle the dataError event

Comment: my combobox inside the DataGridView is ..like static it doesn't extend usually when it's empty i can open it and see just white right?

Comment: Which line this error appears on ?

Comment: hard to tell it seems that is when the DataGridView is being loaded.. My Combobox seems to be freeze i can just hover over it, but i can't select

Comment: I am guessing that somewhere in one of the cells in the combo box column… there is some data in the combo box column cell that is NOT in the `List<string> getApplication` `List`. This is most likely happening when the data is loaded into the grid, which you do not show. How is the grid filled with data and does the data have a column for the combo box values? In addition you wire up the grids `DataError` method, yet, the code appears to do nothing, it may help to see what that error is.

Answer (score 0):

don't i need something like a method SelectedIndexChanged bounded to my combobox inside gridview? to see what i am selecting